# convert the h:m:s in minutes format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data. The idea is to multiply all the data.

however the minute column is in h:m:s format. So whenever i try to multiply i get an error.

and morever i need to convert the h:m:s in minutes format before i actually want to multiply.

tried with the following to convert this to minute

time1 = df['time']

time2 = time1.hour * 60 + time1.minute + time1.second

[image]

Comment: convert your h:m:s into [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) and then perform operations, there are so many convenient methods which can be used to perform these kind of operations. May be that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide by `60`:

```
df['Minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['(MIN)']).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```

If input valeus are python times also convert to strings:

```
df['Minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['(MIN)'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds().div(60)
```